# Commands in Python-Mode not working (py-shell and C-c C-c)

Tags: python

I just installed `python-mode` using melpa and therefore I must be on the latest version.

My `.emacs` init file consists only of the following lines :

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

I try to execute a program that runs fine in the terminal, but when I hit `C-c C-c`, ie. `py-execute-buffer`, there's the following error:

```
py-choose-shell-by-path: Wrong number of arguments: #[nil
```

followed by a trail of gibberish:

[image: Gibberish]

The command `py-shell` will result in the similar error message.

Emacs v24.5
OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Comment: Well, when I delete compiled el files it works fine. So maybe it has something to do with the emacs compiler? I honestly have no clue how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When encountering a bug, please report it to the maintainer, as you will be not the only one affected  and it should get fixed for all.

In case of python-mode.el:

https://code.launchpad.net/python-mode

This time done:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1476933

After looking into `py-choose-shell-by-path`: the lexical-let might have caused the error. Please check out current trunk, should be fixed.